# Regex to to force any character of list occures one and only one time

Tags: regex

I need to have a regex to force characters of a list to occur one and only one time.

For example, if the list is `[1-5]`:

- `14532` should be ACCEPTED
- `252413` should be REJECTED (`2` is repeated more than one time)
- `3152` should be REJECTED (`4` doesn't occur)

Comment: That's not a task for regex. It's a hundred times easier with code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do the task with a (maybe a bit complicated) regex:

```
^(?=.*?1)(?=.*?2)(?=.*?3)(?=.*?4)(?=.*?5)(?!.*?([1-5]).*?\1).*
```

Details:

- `^` - Start of text.
- `(?=.*?1)` - Positive lookahead - require that `1` is present, after any number of chars
  (0 or more).
- `(?=.*?2)(?=.*?3)(?=.*?4)(?=.*?5)` - Similiar positive lookaheads for remaining required
  digits.
- `(?!` - Negative lookahead, the "don't repeat" condition:

  - `.*?` - Any number of chars (0 or more).
  - `([1-5])` - Either of the checked chars. Note that this is a capturing group, as it
    will be "called" soon.
  - `.*?` - Again any number of chars (0 or more).
  - `\1` - The same char which has been matched by group 1.
- `)` - End of negative lookahead.
- `.*` - The text to match (the whole string).

Of course, the last part will match only if all previous lookaheads were satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a programming language, so assuming it be a language or regex engine agnostic and that you know the size of character class (the number of all included characters, here `5`) -  the following regex does the job:

```
^(?:([1-5])(?!.*\1)){5}$
                     ^
```

Having a determined quantifier is the key.

See the [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vMpPwl/1)